# How to pass state from parent to child in a function React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've tried a number of things, and I can pass functions between the components fine, but when I try to pass state from parent to child I get an error saying cannot read undefined

The parent is basically a recyclerlistview and the child is HorizontalScroll

```
Parent

    _renderRow(type, data, index) {
        switch (type) {
            default:
                return (
                    <View key={index} style={styles.container}>
                        <HorizontalScroll
                            data={this.state.data}
                            posts={data}
                        />
                    </View>
                )
            }
    }

   render() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'black'}]}>
                {this.state.loaded && (
                    <RecyclerListView
                        style={{height: fullHeight, width: fullWidth}}
                        extendedState={this.state}
                        rowRenderer={this._renderRow}
                        dataProvider={this.state.dataProvider}
                        layoutProvider={this._layoutProvider}
                        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                        pagingEnabled={true}
                        renderAheadOffset={0}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
        )
    }
```

But when I call this.props.anything in the child component I always get undefined? How can I pass state from parent to child? I can call functions, and I successfully pass functions from parent to child, but I cannot pass state ?

Comment: Have you initialized the state?

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing data from parent to child like this

```
  <HorizontalScroll
   data={this.state.data}
   posts={data}
   />
```

Access in child component like this.

if it's stateful component

```
 this.props.data   // for data

 this.props.posts  // for posts
```

if stateless.

```
props.data        // for data

props.posts       // for posts
```

Answer (score 0):

Im going to leave this question up and answer it because I couldn't find anything relevant on google.

I remembered in react native you need to pass extendedState not just state I dont know why

This doesnt work

```
<ChildComponent 
    data={...this.state}
/>
```

This does

```
<ChildComponent 
    data={this.extendedState}
/>
```

*** edit

My renderRow function was not binded to this in recyclerview in the render function. when I changed

```
rowRenderer={this._renderRow}
```

to

```
rowRenderer=this._renderRow.bind(this)
```

All worked fine and I could pass state properly like

```
data={...this.state}
```

Comment: Since your `renderRow` accepts three params, you can try to pass the state like this in your `rowRenderer`: `rowRenderer={(item, index) => this._renderRow("item.type", this.state.data, index) }`. Then in your child, you can use data directly: `<ChildComponent  data={data}/>`